# create a feature vector using pandas or python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

i have an a binary classifier which takes a 200 element input feature vector as shown below

```
   [ id, v1,   v2, ...,v190, v200, class]
   [  7,   0,   0, ...,   0,    0,    0 ],
   [  8,   0,   1, ...,   0,    0,    1 ],
   [  9,   0,   0, ...,   0,    0,    1 ],
```

For each element X it may have any set of attributes in v1-v200

```
   sql = 'SELECT x_id, x_attr FROM elements WHERE x_hash = %s'
   cur.execute(sql, (x_hash,))
   x1 = cur.fetchone()
   x1 # x1 returns the id and a list of attributes
    (123, [v2,v56,v200])
```

given that output i want to create a feature vector such as the one above, if a attribute in the list matches the any attribute in set v1- v200 then it will be set as a 1.

```
   [  id,   v1,  v2,...,v56,...,v190, v200,    class ],
   [  123,   0,   1,...,1,...,   0,    1,    ?     ],
```

how can i do it in pandas or python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First initializing a pandas dataframe and then building on your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=['v'+str(i) for i in range(1,201)])
sql = 'SELECT x_id, x_attr FROM elements WHERE x_hash = %s'
cur.execute(sql, (x_hash,))
x1_id, features = cur.fetchone()
df.loc[x1_id] = 0  # Initializes all values for the ID to zero.
df.loc[x1_id, features] = 1  # Sets relevant features to a value of one.
```

I haven't included class, as I wasn't sure how you were using it.

Comment: thanks @user4589964 this is what i needed noticed cur.fetchone() returns a tuple, no need for split().